# How to create range slider? (react-native)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

This is my [range slider](https://rnplay.org/apps/Y88nxg)

But for change values user need to click on this value. How to make, to be able to pull the slider? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use PanResponder. Check out the UIExplorer demo for PanResponder. 
http://www.reactnative.com/uiexplorer/

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: On second thought, an easier solution might be to use the [SliderIOS component](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/sliderios.html). If you need a cross platform solution, then [JackDanielsAndCode/react-native-multi-slider](https://github.com/JackDanielsAndCode/react-native-multi-slider) provides a straight JS solution. You can take a peak at his code for an example of using PanResponder if you prefer to roll your own. You might also find [brentvatne/react-native-linear-gradient](https://github.com/brentvatne/react-native-linear-gradient) useful in creating that gradient background

Answer (score 16):

If I were you, without any doubt, I'd search for a library to do the heavy lifting for me.

Assuming you need cross-platform (iOS and Android) range slider solution, based on my research by the time of writing this answer, the plugin which gave the best results in terms of performance on both platforms and customizability options is [@ptomasroos/react-native-multi-slider](https://github.com/ptomasroos/react-native-multi-slider).

It lacks good documentation, but there is [example available](https://github.com/ptomasroos/react-native-multi-slider/tree/master/example). Here's the basic set-up:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import MultiSlider from '@ptomasroos/react-native-multi-slider';

class RangeSlider extends React.Component {
    state = {
        values: [3, 7],
    };

    multiSliderValuesChange = (values) => {
        this.setState({
            values,
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <MultiSlider
                    values={[this.state.values[0], this.state.values[1]]}
                    sliderLength={280}
                    onValuesChange={this.multiSliderValuesChange}
                    min={0}
                    max={10}
                    step={1}
                />
                <Text style={styles.text}>Two Markers:</Text>
                <Text style={styles.text}>{this.state.values[0]}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.text}>{this.state.values[1]}</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Hy I'm using this but can you tell me how to change color?

Answer (score 1):

The creator of [react-native-range-slider](https://github.com/ismnoiet/react-native-range-slider) is here!

You can use this module which is implemented natively and then ported to react-native, thus the great performance and smooth animation.

here is an example:

```
import RangeSlider from 'react-native-range-slider'

<View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
  <RangeSlider
    minValue={0}
    maxValue={100}
    tintColor={'#da0f22'}
    handleBorderWidth={1}
    handleBorderColor="#454d55"
    selectedMinimum={20}
    selectedMaximum={40}
    style={{ flex: 1, height: 70, padding: 10, backgroundColor: '#ddd' }}
    onChange={ (data)=>{ console.log(data);} }
  />
</View>
```

The only limitation and downside here is that it is **only for iOS**(currently).

Comment: is this only for iOS?

Comment: Currently yes .

Comment: any idea how can we use strings in value?

Comment: @Devanshsadhotra if you're talking about parsing strings into numbers then you can use `Number(str)`.

Comment: it's like, i want minValue={'Low'}. it throws error ,

Comment: use `minValue={Number('min number string')}`